# File in use error while calling java.nio.Files.copy(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)

Tags: java, nio

I have a method to copy file:

```
public static void copyFiles(File source, File destination)
{
    try
    {
        destination.setWritable(true);
        Files.copy(source.toPath(), destination.toPath(), java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING,
            java.nio.file.LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I am getting an error while calling this method as:

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\analyticslogs\fsLogs.log: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.copy(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.copy(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Unknown Source)
    at com.platform.module.analytics.util.FileOps.copyFiles(FileOps.java:1417)
    ... 14 more
```

I searched around this and found that my file MAY be kept open by my own program. Am I keeping any resources open or it's a different issue?

Comment: Your code copies a file like it should. What do you mean by `MAY be kept open by my own programm`? Is an other program or the java program you are writing?

Comment: I mean this method is called by my parent program multiple times (sometimes with the same source and destination parameters). I was just wondering if earlier call keeps some resources open which is failing it second time as I see no resources open.

Comment: Paste the entire stack trace, it may help pinpoint the issue. As is, it looks like your destination file is being read from, written to, or kept open. "By another process" is just a generic message.

Comment: Please see the edit for exception stacktrace.

Comment: Since you're copying a log file, I would investigate whether whatever log facility you're using is keeping that file open.